# trying to print a Fibonacci series using producer and consumer pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, producer-consumer

I want to be able to print Fibonacci series using threads, so I'm creating 2 threads:

A producer which will fill the array according to the formula f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2)
A consumer that will print the elements that has been calculated so far

I will set the shared array to be able to store only 5 elements at time, and the consumer will free up space in the array, allowing the producer to add more elements.

This is my consumer code:

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable
{
    private LinkedList<Integer> sharedArray;

public Consumer(LinkedList<Integer> array, int size, int series)
{
    sharedArray = array;

}

@Override
public void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            print();
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void print() throws InterruptedException
{
    while (true)
    {
        synchronized (sharedArray)
        {
            while (sharedArray.isEmpty())
            {
                try
                {
                    sharedArray.wait();
                } catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            System.out.print(sharedArray.get(0) + " ");
            sharedArray.notifyAll();
        }

    }
}

}
```

And this is the producer code:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable

{
private LinkedList<Integer> sharedArray;
private int sharedArraySize;
private int seriesSize;

public Producer(LinkedList<Integer> array, int size, int series)
{
    sharedArray = array;
    sharedArraySize = size;
    seriesSize = series;

}

@Override
public void run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < seriesSize; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            calculate(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void calculate(int n) throws InterruptedException
{
    synchronized (sharedArray)
    {
        while (sharedArray.size() == sharedArraySize)
        {
            sharedArray.wait();
        }
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        {
            sharedArray.add(n, 1);
        } else
        {
            sharedArray.add(n, sharedArray.get(n - 1) + sharedArray.get(n - 2));
        }
        sharedArray.notifyAll();
    }
}

}
```

and the main class that starts both of the threads:

```
public class FibThreads

{


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int seriesSize = 18; //Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int elementsInLine = 0;//Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int sharedArraySize = 5;//Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    LinkedList<Integer> sharedArray = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(sharedArray,sharedArraySize,seriesSize), "Producer");
    Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(sharedArray,sharedArraySize,seriesSize), "Consumer");
    producer.start();
    consumer.start();
    System.out.println("End of main");
}

}
```

**My problem is:** After trying to run this, I get an infinite loop, because as soon as there is a new item in the array, the consumer takes it and free up space, which means the array can't really be filled with items because the consumer frees it immediately.
How can I make it work?

Comment: Can you provide the link to full code? It's little tough with given details

Comment: The error messages would be great and it feels like there is code missing.

Comment: Edited and added all of my code.

Comment: actually now there isn't an error, just an endless loop.
all I get printed is "1 1 1 1 1 1 1...."

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer thats because peekfirst does not remove the first element so it will always be 1

Comment: Can you separate the calculation from the printing?  Perhaps use the array to calculate then put the calculated value into something like a shared `Queue`.  So `print` won't need to know anything about how the value was calculated (separation of concerns).

Comment: @Nordiii it's outdated. I called get(0), not peekfirst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new problem with the only "1" output is because `.get()` does the same like `peekFirst` you get the first element but it does not remove it!

What I assume you want is `System.out.print(sharedArray.pollFirst() + " ");` which retrives the first element and removes it from the linked list.

Your Error was probably because you removed a node but you did not updated `n` in your producer which then pointed to the wrong index as it should be -1 for every removed element.

**EDIT:** Something you should also check is that your consumer does not remove all elements as you need at least 2 to calculate the next fibonacci number!

**EDIT 2:** something like

```
while (sharedArray.isEmpty()||sharedArray.size()<=2)
            {
                try
                {
                    sharedArray.wait();
                } catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }...
```

And you need update N in your producer, you could change it to `sharedArray.add(sharedArray.size(),sharedArray.size()-1+sharedArray.size()-2);` so you would never go out of bounderys.
You can do this because you already check beforehand if you reached the limitation and `n` isn't needed at all.

**EDIT 3:**

`sharedArray.add(sharedArray.size(),sharedArray.size()-1+sharedArray.size()-2);`

should be

`sharedArray.add(sharedArray.size(),sharedArray.get(sharedArray.size()-1)+sharedArray.get(sharedArray.size()-2));`

My bad should have mentioned that....

Comment: That's exactly my probelm, my consumer empty the list. How can I fix it? ideas?

Comment: once I changed it to pollFirst() this is my error:

Exception in thread "Producer" 1 1 

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
 at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.LinkedList.get(Unknown Source)
 at Producer.calculate(Producer.java:46)
 at Producer.run(Producer.java:24)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: I'm having hard time understanding how to update right n in the producer code

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer updated again hopefully it's clear enough :)

Comment: Thanks, after the changes you suggested my output is
1 1 1 3 5 1 3 5 1 3 5 1 3 1 3 5

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer hahahahaa well I guess I should have wrote this in addition updating my post right away

Comment: it works, BUT - the program does not terminate at the end of the printing. deadlock?

Comment: No you just don't terminate your Consumer you could add something like a counter so you can check if all elements you did put out + current size == seriesSize if yes exit else it will wait forever...


|About the deadlock my bad I probably should sleep right now forget about this  ...